# Elasticsearch: how does match query work?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and am confused by how match query works. I have this mapping:

```
{
    "product": {
        "properties": {
            "condition" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes", "index": "analyzed"}
        }
    }
}
```

I bulk imported the following documents

```
{ "index": {"_index": "myindex", "_type": "product", "_id": "1"}}
{ "condition": "All Quiet on the Western Front"}
{ "index": {"_index": "myindex", "_type": "product", "_id": "2"}}
{ "condition": "All Quieter on the Western Front"}
{ "index": {"_index": "myindex", "_type": "product", "_id": "3"}}
{ "condition": "All Quietest on the Western Frontline"}
```

I verified that all documents are loaded successfully. Then I do a match query:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "condition" : "quiet"
        }
    }
}
```

It only returns the #1 document. I am confused here. Why does it not return all three documents? What query should I use to return the three documents because they all have "quiet" root word in the field?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is you are using the default analyzer in Elasticsearch which does not stem (e.g. break words down to their stem, like "quiet" from "quieter" or "quietest").

If you want to stem then the most straightforward thing to do is to use the Snowball analyzer instead. Please note that you need to use this analyzer both for indexing AND for querying otherwise you won't match on stems.

> **snowball analyzer**
>
> An analyzer of type snowball that uses the standard tokenizer, with
>   standard filter, lowercase filter, stop filter, and snowball filter.
>
> The Snowball Analyzer is a stemming analyzer from Lucene that is
>   originally based on the snowball project from snowball.tartarus.org.
>
> Sample usage:

```
{
    "index" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "my_analyzer" : {
                    "type" : "snowball",
                    "language" : "English"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-snowball-analyzer.html

Comment: John, thanks for help! I read everything you mentioned, but have difficulty in where to put snowball into my above example (index and search).

Comment: so after "type":string, add  "analyzer": "snowball", I believe that will be sufficient. if for some reason that does not work you can add the same parameters to your query but I believe it should be okay without it.

Comment: Added "analyzer": "snowball" to the mapping. Recreated the index and loaded the data again. It still does not work with or without "analyzer": "snowball" in query. This is what I used in query: '{
 "query" : {
  "match" : {
   "condition" : {"query": "quieter", "analyzer": "snowball"}
  }
 }
}'